# Do non-Android users throw off the live traffic data provided by Google?

Tags: google-maps, network-traffic

I was trying to get a better understanding of how Google reports live traffic on Google maps/navigation and came across this explanation from Google:

> "When we combine your speed with the speed of other phones on the road, across thousands of phones moving around a city at any given time, we can get a pretty good picture of live traffic conditions"

My question is whether or not location data is amassed from users not using Google products in order to provide the most accurate traffic conditions possible. Any insight would be great.

Comment: Yes;  Google Maps will transfer data back to Google in order to function.   If your using Google Maps your using a Google product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Google purchased [Waze](https://www.waze.com/) a little while ago, their traffic data has used input from Waze.  This is irrespective of the phone OS on which the app is running.

Waze is not the only source of information, any app that can give Google positional - and thus speed - can add to the accuracy of the data.

The traffic information is derived from speed, not the number of phones in an area.  Therefore, phones not running Android don't 'throw off' the data, they just don't add to it.